# make_path does not set mode as specified

Tags: perl, path, permissions

When I call `make_path` (from the core [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) module, supplying a mode, the directory that is created does not have the mode I requested:

```
$ perl -MFile::Path=make_path -e 'make_path("foobar", { mode=>0770 });'
$ ls -ld foobar/
drwxr-x--- 2 itk itkadm 4096 Sep 19 11:10 foobar/
```

I was expecting to see:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 itk itkadm 4096 Sep 19 11:07 foobar/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this detail in the [`make_path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html#DESCRIPTION) documentation:

> mode: The numeric permissions mode to apply to each created directory
>   (defaults to 0777), **to be modified by the current umask**.

I was not expecting this because the shell equivalent (`mkdir -m 0770 -p foobar`)  does not consider [`umask`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html).

This works as expected:

```
$ perl -MFile::Path=make_path -e 'umask(0); make_path("foobar", { mode=>0770 });'
$ ls -ld foobar/
drwxrwx--- 2 itk itkadm 4096 Sep 19 11:13 foobar/
```

Note the `umask(0)`.

As pointed out by Evan Carroll, the version of `File::Path` supplued with newer perl versions (>=5.24) have a `chmod` option which may be a more convenient way to set the mode of created directories.

Comment: just use chmod if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting the permissions for the directory to `0`. Try instead just using the `chmod` option to `File::Path::make_path`

```
perl -MFile::Path=make_path -e 'make_path("foobar", { chmod=>0770 });'
```

Comment: That chmod option was added in perl 5.24. It was not present when I had this issue.